# Does Netty 4 support UDP multicast with IGMPv3?

Tags: java, netty, igmp

I've been unable to find any reference to Netty 4 supporting UDP multicast with IGMPv3 in the documentation.

Can anyone clarify if this is supported or not?

Comment: Is it ever supported by JDK?

Comment: The javadoc for MulticastChannel states "It may optionally support source filtering as specified by RFC 3376: Internet Group Management Protocol, Version 3 (IGMPv3)". What isn't clear is if optionally refers to the implementation or an option you need to specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything that is possible with plain jdk7 should also be possible with Netty in terms of multicast.

From [Netty Discussions Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netty/CXZZE5UGotc)